# Airflow cannot run cli commands

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I set up Airflow using Kubernetes and another standalone Postgres server.
When I run `airflow list_dags` inside a container, i get `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`.

Where can i check what connection that CLI is using?

Comment: do you have a  service definition named "postgres" for `Postgres server` ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the container doesn't have `AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN` environment variable set up.

Comment: How did you even get it working on Kubernetes? I'm trying to use puckel's airflow image on GKE and can't get it to work. Can you please guide me?

Comment: what step did you get stuck?

Comment: I converted the docker-compose files into Kubernetes files, but couldn't go further than that. Wonder if there's a way to communicate privately and not spam the comment section of the answer.